# Assign a value to fields of chronoforms to calculate a final sum

Tags: forms, sum, field, chronoforms

i am using the Chronoforms plugin for Joomla 3.2.
I have created a form with different fields inside (text box,checkbox,upload) that the user should complete. I have created the db table connected at the form also.
I need to assign a numeric value for each field of the form and to calculate a final sum of these according to how many fields have been filled by the user. The relut have to be visible and necessary only to to the administrator, no visible for the user.
For example: if every field has been filled, the sum will be 100, otherwise it will be a numeric value <100.
I think is required javascript code but i don't know it a lot to resolve my problem.

Comment: For more detailed answers, you'll probably need to specify which version of ChronoForms you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If the results only have to be visible to the administrator, then you don't need to use any JavaScript.

All you need to do is add a Custom Code action to your form and the total can be calculated using PHP after the form is submitted. The total can then be emailed to an administrator and/or written to the database.

Comment: I use Chronoform v4. I don't know the PHP. How would be the code for assign a value to each field in the form and to calculate the total sum?

Comment: The value that i will assign have to considered only if the field has been compilated by the user otherwise the value will be 0.